# Как можно улучшить код?

Tags: pascal, инспекция-кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
program lr3;
var x,y : real;
begin
    readln(x);
    if (sqr(sin(x))>=1/2) then
        y:=-2*sqr(sin(x));
    if (1/4 < sqr(sin(x))) then
        if(sqr(sin(x)) < 1/2) then
            y:=0.0000016;
    if(sqr(sin(x))<=1/4) then
          y:=sqr(tan(x));
   writeln(y);
end.
```

Comment: Нет смысла вычислять заново уже вычисленное...

Answer (score 1):

```
program lr3;
var x, y: double;
var sinX2: double;
begin
  readln(x);
  sinX2 := sqr(sin(x));
  if sinX2 >= 0.5 then
  begin
    y := -2 * sinX2;
  end
  else if sinX2 > 0.25 then
  begin
    y := -1.6E-6;
  end
  else
  begin
    y := sqr(tan(x));
  end;
  writeln(y);
end.
```

Comment: Только `y := -1.6E-6;`, в исходном тоже ошибка.

Comment: @Alekcvp спасибо, поправил